# Using parameters inside state file

Tags: salt-stack

I'm playing with salt, and I came in to a dead end.

My state file should make a backup of a file before edit/change the file. 
I don't like the build-in backup function because (as far as I understood), when I run backup it copy the file to  /var/cache/salt/minion/.... if I'll run it again the backup will overwrite the last version
So, I created a backup script in bash 
The script handle two parameters [file to backup] [comment]

My plan is to run the script just before every state that changes my minion files.

That's my sls file:

```
 bck:
   #Copy the backup script to minion 
   file.managed:
      - name: /bin/bck
      - source: salt://bin/bck
      - template: jinja
      - user: root
      - group: root
      - mode: 0773

 myscript:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /bin/bck 
    #- name: /bin/bck /etc/sysctl.conf GILI > /dev/null 2>&1
    - cwd: /
#    - stateful: True

 vm.swappiness:
    sysctl.present:
#      - cmd:  myscript {{ GILI }}
       - cmd:  myscript /etc/sysctl.conf GILI
#       - args: "/etc/sysctl.conf GILI > /dev/null 2>&1"
#      - GILI: /etc/hosts GGGGGGG
      - value: 20
```

Comments didn't worked, and also that sample didn't work (I can't see that my bck script is running.

If I remove the comment from "**#    - stateful: True**" the script run OK, but it run independently and not from the "vm.swappiness"

Help please :)

Gili

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a "require" to chain these together. Also, I'd probably use `cmd.script` for your backup script. It would look something like this:

```
my_backup_script:
  cmd.script:
    - source: salt://bin/bck

vm.swappiness:
  sysctl.present:
    - value: 20
    - require:
      - cmd: my_backup_script
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me :)

My backup script need two parameters, first - the file to backup and second is a comment.
How do i integrate parameters?
I tried like that:  - cmd: my_backup_script /etc/sysctl.conf Backup
And it fails (     Function: cmd.script
      Result: False
     Comment: Command 'my_backup_script' run
     Started: 10:44:58.020214
    Duration: 37.31 ms)